# Оптимизация кода на Js, Html, Css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как я могу оптимизировать ещё больше код? Я начинающий.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zola</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
    <body>
          <div class="buttonBlock">
            <p>
              Если бы тебе предложили эти 3 блюда, какое бы ты выбрал? <br>
              <button id="but1" class="but" onclick="tap('but1', 'but2', 'but3')">Пиццу</button>
              <button id="but2" class="but" onclick="tap('but2', 'but1', 'but3')">Пельмени</button>
              <button id="but3" class="but" onclick="tap('but3', 'but1', 'but2')">Курицу</button>
            </p>
            <p>
              Какое из этих деревьев бы обнял потому, что любишь? <br>
              <button id="but4" class="but" onclick="tap('but4', 'but5', 'but6')">Берёзу</button>
              <button id="but5" class="but" onclick="tap('but5', 'but4', 'but6')">Ёлку</button>
              <button id="but6" class="but" onclick="tap('but6', 'but4', 'but5')">Осину</button>
            </p>
            <p>
              В какой из этих стран лучше всего жить? <br>
              <button id="but7" class="but" onclick="tap('but7', 'but8', 'but9')">В России</button>
              <button id="but8" class="but" onclick="tap('but8', 'but7', 'but9')">В Украине</button>
              <button id="but9" class="but" onclick="tap('but9', 'but7', 'but8')">В Америке</button>
            </p>
            <p>
              Что бы ты закричал, если бы к тебе в туалет зашёл Lololoshka? <br>
              <button id="but10" class="but" onclick="tap('but10', 'but11', 'but12')">Мама</button>
              <button id="but11" class="but" onclick="tap('but11', 'but10', 'but12')">Ёшкин дрын</button>
              <button id="but12" class="but" onclick="tap('but12', 'but11', 'but10')">Насик жив!</button>
            </p>
            <p>
              Какое из этих животных любишь больше всего? <br>
              <button id="but13" class="but" onclick="tap('but13', 'but14', 'but15')">Коня</button>
              <button id="but14" class="but" onclick="tap('but14', 'but13', 'but15')">Собаку</button>
              <button id="but15" class="but" onclick="tap('but15', 'but13', 'but14')">Кошку</button>
            </p>
            <button class="butResult" onclick="act()" type="button" name="button">Принять</button>
          </div>
        <div id="output" class="outputE"> Хай мазафака </div>

      <script src="worker.js">
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 let a = b = c = d = e = 'Сначала ответь на все вопросы, жопа! '
function tap(get, z, x) {
  let element = document.getElementById(get);
  element.classList.toggle("butAct");
   element.classList.toggle("but");
    let y = document.getElementById(z)
  y.classList.remove("butAct")
  let w = document.getElementById(x)
  w.classList.remove("butAct")
  if (get == 'but1' || get == 'but2' || get == 'but3') {
  a = document.getElementById(get).textContent;
  } else if (get == 'but4' || get == 'but5' || get == 'but6') {
  b = document.getElementById(get).textContent;
  } else if (get == 'but7' || get == 'but8' || get == 'but9') {
  c = document.getElementById(get).textContent;
  } else if (get == 'but10' || get == 'but11' || get == 'but12') {
 d = document.getElementById(get).textContent;
  } else if (get == 'but13' || get == 'but14' || get == 'but15') {
  e = document.getElementById(get).textContent;
  }
}
function act() {
  co = document.getElementById('output');
  console.log(a);
  if (a != 'Сначала ответь на все вопросы, жопа! ' & b != 'Сначала ответь на все вопросы, жопа! ' & c != 'Сначала ответь на все вопросы, жопа! ' & e != 'Сначала ответь на все вопросы, жопа! ' & d != 'Сначала ответь на все вопросы, жопа! ') {
    co.innerHTML = (`Егор ${c}, залезая на высоченную ${b}, орал \"${d}!\" и поедал ${a}, держа подмышкой ${e}`);
  } else {
    co.innerHTML = 'Сначала ответь на все вопросы, жопа! ';
  }
}
```

CSS

```
* {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.butAct {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0 , 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #80E800;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-kerning: auto;
}
.but:hover {
  border: 10px, solid, red;
  color: #B7F46E;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
button {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(191, 130, 48, 0.6);
  border-radius: 5px
}
.butResult {
  font-size: 30px
}

body {
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/1c/d4/d2/1cd4d2ceabd9ed87cc41f3cf8de3d3c4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover
}
.buttonBlock {
  width: 580px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 60px;
}

.outputE {
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 85px;
  top: 60px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну его не "оптимизировать" нужно, а переписывать)

1. атрибуты `onclick` и `onдругие` были актуальны, когда скрипты на страницах занимали всего несколько строчек. Они давно устарели: Стоит держать HTML отдельно, скрипт - отдельно, и вместо него использовать `element.addEventListener("click", function() {   })`;
2. Как только начинаются нумерованные id, имена классов и прочее, что повторяется, и нужно вручную заполнять - значит явно что-то идет не так: Нужно думать, как выполнить ту же задачу через циклы.
3. Не надо стесняться давать переменным нормальные имена. Программы пишут для людей, а не для кампуктёров. Чтобы в идеале, читая название переменной, сразу понимать, что там хранится. Однобуквенные переменные ни о чем не говорят. (Исключение: Случаи, когда из контекста кода очевидно, о чем эта буква... координаты `x, y`, радиус `r`, счетчики для циклов `i, j, k`).
4. К тому же, `let a = b = c = d = e = 'Какая-то строка'` у вас тут нормально объявляется только первая переменная. Все остальные выдали бы ошибку в строгом режиме, но здесь JS сам за кулисами создает глобальные переменные с такими названиями, что не есть хорошо. Если правда будет нужна такая конструкция (вряд ли), можно оформить это в таком виде:

`let a, b, c, d, e;`

`a = b = c = d = e = ...`

5. `&` это побитовый [оператор 'И'](https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators). Логическое 'И' выглядит так: `&&`
6. Узнаю стиль W3Schools) Переключитесь на что-то другое: http://learn.javascript.ru/ , https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/
7. Если опрос будет не забавы ради, а достаточно длинным, есть смысл создать объект со всеми вопросами-вариантами, а весь HTML вставить не вручную, а также из JS, через цикл. А это уже другая история)

P.s. Светло-какашечный плохо сочетается с синим и фиолетовым... =_='

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".but");

btns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let active = this.parentNode.querySelector(".but.active");
    if( active ) active.classList.remove("active");
    this.classList.add("active");  
  });
});

let btnResult = document.querySelector(".butResult");
btnResult.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let questions = document.querySelectorAll("p");  
  let answers = document.querySelectorAll(".but.active");  
  let output = document.getElementById('output');
  
  if( answers.length < questions.length ) {
    output.textContent = 'Сначала ответь на все вопросы!';
    return;
  }
  
  output.textContent = `Егор ${answer(0)}, залезая на высоченную ${answer(1)}, орал "${answer(2)}!" и поедал ${answer(3)}, держа подмышкой ${answer(4)}`;
  // Таких длинных строк стоит избегать, но бывают исключения.
  
  function answer(index) {
    return answers[index].textContent;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.but.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #80E800;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-kerning: auto;
}

.but:hover {
  border: 10px, solid, red;
  color: #B7F46E;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px
}

.butResult {
  font-size: 30px
}

body {
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/1c/d4/d2/1cd4d2ceabd9ed87cc41f3cf8de3d3c4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover
}

.buttonBlock {
  width: 580px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 60px;
}

.outputE {
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonBlock">
  <p>
    В какой из этих стран лучше всего жить? <br>
    <button class="but">В России</button>
    <button class="but">В Украине</button>
    <button class="but">В Америке</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    Какое из этих деревьев бы обнял потому, что любишь? <br>
    <button class="but">Берёзу</button>
    <button class="but">Ёлку</button>
    <button class="but">Осину</button>
  </p>  
  <p>
    Что бы ты закричал, если бы к тебе в туалет зашёл Lololoshka? <br>
    <button class="but">Мама</button>
    <button class="but">Ёшкин дрын</button>
    <button class="but">Насик жив!</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    Если бы тебе предложили эти 3 блюда, какое бы ты выбрал? <br>
    <button class="but">Пиццу</button>
    <button class="but">Пельмени</button>
    <button class="but">Курицу</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    Какое из этих животных любишь больше всего? <br>
    <button class="but">Коня</button>
    <button class="but">Собаку</button>
    <button class="but">Кошку</button>
  </p>
  <button class="butResult" type="button" name="button">Принять</button>
</div>
<div id="output" class="outputE"> Хай </div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за пищу для размышлений, а насчёт "узнаю стиль W3Schools" - всё ещё хуже, "учился", просто хватая информацию где придется, на htmlbook, что-то в Ютубе и т.д